# Gitlab profile button?

Tags: profile, gitlab

It's relatively easy to add a [GitHub button](https://buttons.github.io/) to a webpage as a way to link to one's profile.  I'm trying to find an analogous button for my Gitlab account. Does such a button exist?

Answer (score 1):

GitLab doesn't currently have convenient buttons to add like GitHub does. However, you could fork the [GitHub button source code](https://github.com/ntkme/github-buttons) (licensed under the BSD 2-clause "Simplified" License) and make a GitLab version of the button.